# Show that Lie algebra $L$ is solvable (nilpotent) if and only if $ad(L)$ is solvable (nilpotent)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

Show that Lie algebra $L$ is solvable (nilpotent) if and only if $ad(L)$ is solvable (nilpotent).

If $L$ is solvable, then $ad(L)$ is the image of $L$ under a lie algebra morphism and so will be solvable. I would appreciate some help with the $(\leftarrow)$ as well as the nilpotent cases... I've been scratching my head for awhile on this one.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1. If $$0 \rightarrow L_1 \rightarrow L_2 \rightarrow L_3 \rightarrow 0$$ is an exact sequence of Lie algebras, what do you know about solvability / nilpotency of $L_2$ related to solvability / nilpotency of $L_1$ and $L_3$?

Added: Every introductory treatment on solvable / nilpotent Lie algebras should contain the (easily proven) lemmata I am alluding to here, maybe in different language. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_Lie_algebra#Properties) phrases it like this, referencing standard textbooks by Serre and Knapp:

> Given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and an ideal $\mathfrak h$ in it,
> $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable if and only if both $\mathfrak h$ and $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak h$ are solvable.
> The analogous statement is true for nilpotent Lie algebras provided $\mathfrak h$ is contained in the center. Thus, an extension of a solvable algebra by a solvable algebra is solvable, while a *central* extension of a nilpotent algebra by a nilpotent algebra is nilpotent.

2. What is $\ker(ad)$?

Comment: Hmm well lie algebras are sort of like vector spaces so I'll assume that this sequence splits, in which case $L_2$ is solvable $\iff$ $L_1$ and $L_3$ are solvable.... Also $ker(ad)=Z(L)$. So you're saying look at $0 \rightarrow Z(L) \rightarrow L \rightarrow \frac{L}{Z(L)} \rightarrow 0$ 

Is $ad: L \rightarrow gl(L)$ surjective?? No way... Hmm i'm a bit confused still, but great hints!! got any others?

Comment: Sequences like that do *not* split in general, but still every introductory treatment on solvable and nilpotent Lie algebras should contain easily proved lemmata about what happens in such sequences. See edit. -- $ad$ is certainly not surjective when we take $gl(L)$ as its codomain, but we might just restrict to its image ...